# Manual collection check boxes in Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm building a form using Simple Form where I must manually loop over a collection of records which are candidates for a HABTM relationship. I must do a manual loop because I need to render additional information about the records in a table, so I can't use Simple Form's `collection_check_boxes`.

Models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foos
end
```

View so far (HAML):

```
= f.simple_for_form @foo do |f|
  %table
    - @bars.each do |bar|
      %tr
        %td
          # Line of interest:
          = f.input :bar_ids, as: :boolean, label: bar.name
        %td
          = bar.additional_information
```

How do I tell Simple Form that `f.input :bar_ids` is part of an array so that it will name the field `foo[bar_ids][]` and assign a value of `bar.id`?

Comment: does simple_form have "fields_for" ?

Comment: Yeah, `#simple_fields_for` (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#simple-fields-for)

Comment: I'm guessing, but I'd have a go with something like `.simple_fields_for :bars do |bar_form|` instead of just your `.each`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's reasonably straightforward, thanks to [this post from 2012](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-simpleform/30_9T1I_CJg).

```
= f.simple_for_form @foo do |f|
  %table
    = f.collection_check_boxes :bars, @bars, :id, :name do |builder|
      %tr
        %td
          = builder.check_box
          = builder.label 
        %td
          = builder.object.additional_information
```

Answer (score -1):

You can test

> f.input :bar_ids, as: :boolean, label: bar.name, as: :checkboxes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).